# Adding a row vector to a 3-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 3-D array in numpy

```
a = [ [[1,2], [3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8]] ]
```

I want to add a new row vector to a matrix so that the output would be for example, if I wanted to add the row vector [9,10] to the second matrix in the 3d array:

```
a = [ [[1,2], [3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8], [9,10]] ]
```

I know how to add row vectors to 2-D arrays using `np.append`. But I don't know how to do it with 3-D arrays. I have tried to use `np.append` but all I get are either dimension errors, flattened arrays or just the wrong array. What would be the correct way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Perhaps?
```aa = np.asarray([ [[1,2], [3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8]] ])``` followed by 
```  aa[1,1,:] = np.asarray([9,10])```

Comment: You can't.  Try `np.array(a)` with the desired `a`. You won't get a 3d array.  It's trying to join a (2,2) with (3,2).  That can't make a (2,?,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy does memory optimization and creates `np.ndarray` of the size that you requested. It's better that you create an array of the size that you need at once and manipulate it instead of adding new rows many times.

So, if you will use many appends: use list. If you know the total size: use numpy array.

Another problem that you face is: The shape is not uniform. That is

```py
a = np.array([ [[1,2], [3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8]] ])
# a.shape is (2, 2, 2)
new_a = np.array([ [[1,2], [3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8], [9, 10] ]])
# What is the shape of new_a?
```

A code that does what you want is:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ [[1,2], [3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8]] ])
b = np.array([9,10])


res = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype="object")
res[0] = a[0]
res[1] = np.zeros((a.shape[1]+1, a.shape[2]))
res[1, :-1] = a[1, :]
res[1, -1] = b
```